# Can I preview the line of JavaScript code that is executed on Firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox, firebug

Lets say for example that I have a button and when I click on it a modal dialog opens on the screen, or I have a vertical navigation and when I click on an item, it shows all the sub-items of this one.

I was wondering if it's possible to preview on Firebug, which lines of code are executed and see the specific code of the JavaScript file?

What I'm looking for is a way of viewing the JS code that is executed in a similar way as Firebug does with CSS (by doing *Inspect Element with Firebug* on a tag and showing all CSS rules that are applied to this tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Script panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) to view and debug your JavaScript code.

There are several ways of how you can debug your code:

1. Setting a breakpoint
2. Using the `debugger` keyword
3. Using the [Break On ...](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging) feature

In all these cases the script execution will stop at a specific line, from which you can step through each instruction to debug the code.

How you do that is [described in more detail on the Firebug wiki page](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Break_On_...).

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand correct, but what I want to do is when I click a button, for instance, to see the js code that is executed and pops-up the dialog.. I'm not actually trying to debug the code, but find it on which file and line is located

Comment: Yes, just hit the [Break On Next](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Break_On_Next) button inside the *Script* panel and then click the button on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can debug (see) your js code.

In firebug Script panel is provided where you can select your js and attach debugger wherever you want.